# Docker контейнер не видит девайсы на хосте (serialport)

Tags: bash, usb, docker, serial

Нужно запустить Docker-контейнер с доступом к serial-порту на хосте.

Вот как я это делал:

- использовал MAC
- установил дрова на хосте
  (http://www.prolific.com.tw/US/ShowProduct.aspx?p_id=229&pcid=41)
- подключил девайс
- запустил на хосте `ls /dev/t*` который возвратил девайс `/dev/tty.usbserial` - он есть и работает
- запустил docker-контейнер `docker run -it --privileged -v /dev:/dev node:4.4.0 /bin/bash` и далее `ls /dev/t*` внутри контейнера, но это не возвратило нужного девайса `/dev/tty.usbserial`...

Я пробовал много разных вариантов параметров, но пока не нашел работающего варианта :) К слову, `--device` флаг не подходит, т.к. девайс может быть переподключен и его имя после подключения может измениться  и стать отличным от `/dev/tty.usbserial`

Comment: docker run -t -i --privileged -v //dev/tty.usbserial:/dev/tty.usbserial ubuntu bash